# How to test to ensure an interface has no other methods than those listed?

Tags: c#, .net, unit-testing, testing

The situation is that we have a plugin interface.  We want to make sure the interface has the methods listed in the acceptance criteria and no others.  How would one go about this?  Currently using NUnit and Moq, but if not achievable with these, please advise on alternatives.

For example:

```
Public Interface IPlugin {
  bool Start();
  bool Stop();
}
```

We have tests for calling them and receiving a returned value, no problem.  But how can we test to make sure that IPlugin ONLY has Start and Stop and no others like Restart() or something?

Comment: Why do you need to test for this?

Comment: You can't tell just by looking at the interface?  I'm not being flippant; unit tests are supposed to test behavior, not structure.  Adding a method to the interface will break all of the classes that inherit it, so it's not like it's not going to get noticed.

Comment: Yeah, I know this is not a normal thing to test.  Problem is that we have international teams that will be adding their own plugins.  We are the core team that defines the interface to which they need to adhere.  It is essentially a workaround for a process issue.

Comment: No reason to use an automated unit test for this, just use your sourcecontrol system to restrict access to those in non-core teams to checking in a change to the file which defines the interface.

Comment: @EkoostikMartin That is a better workaround that hacking up some unit tests.  I'm going to give that route a go.  Thanks.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Use [reflection](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/f7ykdhsy.aspx), such as the [Type.GetMethods](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.type.getmethods.aspx) method:

```
Type myType =(typeof(IPlugin));

// Get the public methods.
MethodInfo[] myArrayMethodInfo = myType.GetMethods();

Console.WriteLine("The number of public methods is {0}.", myArrayMethodInfo.Length);
```

Comment: Although I'm going to try to go with @EkoostikMartin's approach first (fingers crossed on process change approval ;) ), this was the first correct direct answer to the question.

Comment: +1. This is a way, also useless to extent for this particular case as whoever changed interface should be able to change check in the test against `myArrayMethodInfo.Length` :)

Answer (score 3):

If `IPlugin` is an interface defined by you, within your assembly, the methods will be known at compile time.  There is no reason to check for other methods, as the interface itself has a known, fixed structure.

Classes implementing this interface should be free to have any other methods desired, which would be part of the internal implementation.  The `Start()` and `Stop()` methods would merely be required to fulfill your contract.

---

If you want to verify that your interface hasn't been changed by a developer, you could use reflection:

```
MethodInfo[] methods = typeof(IPlugin).GetMethods();

// Check that there are only 2 methods, with the names you desire
Assert.AreEqual(methods.Length, 2);
var allowedMethodNames = new[] {"Start", "Stop"};
if (!methods.All(m => allowedMethodNames.Contains(m.Name)))
{
    // Method not contained in allowed names...
}
```

Comment: Not worried about testing the concrete objects and whether they have added methods.  The question is how can we validate the contract has not changed via an automated test system.

Comment: @JohnS. I'd argue that is really not something necessarily appropriate for unit testing, but you can do it easily via reflection (added code).

Comment: @JohnS. You can not - if someone can change the interface they will be able to change your test system too at the same time.

Comment: @AlexeiLevenkov Unless they don't have access to the test project ;)

Answer (score 3):

Use `typeof(IPlugin).GetMethods()`, and enumerate the resulting list
 in your unit test.

Answer (score 2):

Instead of using an automated unit test for this, just use your source control system to restrict access from those in non-core teams to checking in a change to the file which defines the interface.

Answer (score 1):

This is out of the scope of unit-testing. Unit-testing is about testing the behavior of a single public method/property. The test should not dictate in any way the implementation details of the tested functionality.